# Best practise to orchestrate small python task (mostly executing SQL in BigQuery)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are using pubsub and cloud functions in GCP to orchestrate our data workflow.

Our workflow is something like :

[workflow_gcp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUswT.png)

pubsub1 and pubsub3 can be triggered at different times (ex: 1am and 4am). They are triggered daily, from an external source (our ETL, Talend).

Our cloud functions basically execute SQL in BigQuery.

This is working well but we had to manually create a orchestration database to log when functions start and end (to answer the question "function X executed ok?"). And the orchestration logic is strongly coupled with our business logic, since our cloud function must know what functions has to be executed before, and what pubsub to trigger after.

So we're looking for a solution that separate the orchestration logic and the business logic.

I found that composer (airflow) could be a solution, but :

- it can't run cloud function natively (and with API it's very limited, 16 calls par 100 seconds per project)
- we can use BigQuery inside airflow with BigQuery operators, but orchestration and business logics would be strongly coupled again

So what is the best practise in our case?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This seems like a pretty big question with many angles. 
Would be good if you shared some examples or cold-runs of current and expected variants.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What do you mean by cold run? I shared a graphic, that is a pretty good example of what we want to achieve. I know this problem could by solved in many ways, I just wanted to have some ideas, maybe some feedback from those who succeeded in implementing airflow like we want to do.

Comment: Sorry, probably the literal translation doesn't make sense. I mean a few examples of input - process - output, so it is easier to visualise the task at hand. A flow diagram or something of the sorts would also help

Comment: I made a flow diagram example (i cannot make it appear as an image since I'm a new user) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUswT.png

Comment: From our ETL, we load data "as-is" from Oracle (on-premise) to BigQuery. Let's say its "clients" table. When this job succeeds, it publishes a message in a pubsub topic, that launch a deduplication task (cloud function). When this function ends, it publishes a message in pubsub, triggering a data quality function. On parallel, there's another pipeline working the same way, but with different data, let's say "purchases". And when these two pipeline succeeds, we run a third function that create an aggragate view of clients / purchases.

Comment: Thanks for the context. 
I fail to see why Cloud Composer (Airflow) won't be a good solution here. This is literally the use case for Airflow. 
I'd rather not post an answer yet just in case I haven't understood your problem properly, but I am a certified GCP Data Engineer, and this type of orchestration jobs are a perfect match for Airflow. 
Just keep in mind, you will only schedule, define dependencies, and trigger jobs in Airflow, I don't recommend you using the jobs to actually do the processing. 
Anything I am missing?

Comment: yes that is correct. Airflow seems like a good idea, but how can I run my cloud functions from airflow? Or is there an other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cloud Composer (Airflow) and still reutilise most of your existing set-up.

Firstly, you can keep all your existing Cloud Functions and use [HTTP triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) (or others you prefer) to trigger them in Airflow. The only change you will need to do is to implement a [PubSub Sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/sensors/pubsub_sensor.html) in Airflow, so it triggers your Cloud Functions (therefore ensuring you can control orchestration from end to end of your process).

Your solution will be an Airflow [DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#dags) that triggers the Cloud Functions based on the PubSub messages, reports back to Airflow if the functions were successful and then, if both were successful, trigger the third Cloud Function with an HTTP trigger or similar, just the same.

A final note, which is not immediately intuitive. Airflow is not meant to run the jobs itself, it is meant to orchestrate and manage dependencies. The fact that you use Cloud Functions triggered by Airflow is not an anti-pattern, is actually a best practice.

In your case, you could 100% rewrite a few things and use the BigQuery operators, as you don't do any processing, just triggering of queries/jobs, but the concept stays true, the best practice is leveraging Airflow to make sure things happen when and in the order you need, not to process those things itself. (Hope that made any sense)

Comment: Its a very good suggestion to drop the cloud function and use bigqueryoperator

Comment: I don't think so because it would strongly couple business and orchestration logic. But that would do the job for sure. Also we would have to rewrite all our code.

Comment: I am not sure about that strongly coupling you are talking about. Could you give me an example or a counterexample? I want to make sure I understand your concern

Comment: thanks Francesco Galletta for you answer. I'm ok with your solution, but I don't know how to implement it. I already tried to implement a pubsub sensor, that works OK. One question : what should I use as a starter for my DAG? Can you make a DAG always running and waiting for my pubsub sensor?
Also, how do you trigger the cloud function? I tried but it's very difficult cause there's no operator to run a cloud function natively. It exists in newer version of airflow but very limited (16 calls per 100 seconds). I could use pubsub but that would be asynchronous, so I won't know when my job ends.

Comment: When talking about coupling, I was answering to Anders Elton, not you ;)

Comment: Yeah. Your sensor will essentially be the ignition. 
Just to make it clearer, a DAG is not "a run of tasks", is actually the sequence and dependencies definition of some tasks. This means, your DAG is not what actually process anything, but it is what makes sure that the things happen in the order that you want them to. 

Contrary to initial intuition, which might make you think the DAG is "a run of a series of somethings". That's a concept initially hard to understand.

Don't use the CF operator, just send HTTP triggers, that shouldn't pose any problems.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to airflow I would have looked at "argo workflows" -> https://github.com/argoproj/argo

It doesnt have the cost overhead the composer has, especially for smaller workloads.

I would have:

Created a deployment that read pubsub messages from external tool and deployed this to kubernetes.

Based on message executed a workflow.  Each step in the workflow could be a cloud function, packaged in docker.

(I would have replaced the cloud function with a kubernetes job, which is then triggered by the workflow.)

It is pretty straight forward to package a cloud function with docker and run it in kuberentes.

There exists prebuilt docker images with gsutil/bq/gcloud, so you could create bash scripts that uses "bq" command line to execute stuff inside bigquery.

Comment: Thanks for your help.This could be a solution, but for us it's new skills that we don't have. Our team is very small (3 people) and we have to do the development, and also the supervision of this worflow (and that part is only a tiny part of what we do in our company). That's why we choose to do cloud function. And mostly we do SQL requests, that is our main skill.